# Linq, EF4, Filter data after Linq query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I'd like to filter the result that after Linq query.

and make it to List() or Array().

Here is my code,

```
//for test, filter is always true
bool filter = true;

OrdersRepository ordersRepository = new OrdersRepository();

var productInQuery = ordersRepository.ProductIn;
var productOutQuery = ordersRepository.ProductOut;
var productQuery = ordersRepository.Product;
var orderInfoQuery = ordersRepository.OrderInfo;

var result = (from p in productInQuery
      join o in orderInfoQuery on p.refNo equals o.refNo
      join x in productQuery on p.productNo equals x.no
      join t in productOutQuery on p.no equals t.productInNo into productIn
      from t in productIn.DefaultIfEmpty()
      orderby o.processDate descending
      select new reportModel
      {
          yourRef = o.yourRefNo,
          modelNo = x.modelNo,
          mfgNo = p.mfgNo,
          serialNo = p.serialNo,
          poNo = p.poNo,
          lbs =  p.lbs,
          width = p.width,
          height = p.height,
          depth = p.depth,
          qty = p.qty,
          dateIn = o.processDate,
          dateOut = (from m in orderInfoQuery where m.refNo == t.refNo select m.processDate).FirstOrDefault(),
          etaDate = (from w in orderInfoQuery where w.refNo == t.refNo select w.eta).FirstOrDefault()
      });

// Filter one more time
if (filter)
{
    List<reportModel> a = (from q in result
         where q.etaDate >= new DateTime(2012, 5, 20)
         select q).ToList();

    //var a = result.Where(q => q.etaDate >= new DateTime(2012, 5, 20)).ToList(); //I tried this too, but it does not work either.
}
else
{
    var a = result.ToList();
}
```

**When run the above code, an error message occur.**

```
Specified method is not supported.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

Source Error: 


Line 64:                  */
Line 65: 
Line 66:                 var a = result.Where(q => q.etaDate >= new DateTime(2012, 5, 20)).ToList();
Line 67:             }
Line 68:             else

Source File: WebUI\Controllers\TestController.cs    Line: 66 

Stack Trace: 


[NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.]
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.Visit(DbApplyExpression expression) +28
   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbApplyExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +23
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +35
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +21
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression) +38
   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +23
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +35
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +21
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbFilterExpression expression) +37
   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbFilterExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +23
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +35
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +21
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression) +38
   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +23
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +35
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +21
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression) +38
   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +23
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +35
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +21
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbSortExpression expression) +63
   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbSortExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +23
   MySql.Data.Entity.SqlGenerator.VisitInputExpression(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +35
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.VisitInputExpressionEnsureSelect(DbExpression e, String name, TypeUsage type) +21
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.Visit(DbProjectExpression expression) +38
   System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept(DbExpressionVisitor`1 visitor) +23
   MySql.Data.Entity.SelectGenerator.GenerateSQL(DbCommandTree tree) +60
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree) +334
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree) +147
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree) +526

[EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree) +1329
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree) +97
   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree) +198
   System.Data.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree) +147
   System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Span span, ReadOnlyCollection`1 compiledQueryParameters) +397
   System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +696
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption) +149
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() +44
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +40
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TResult>.GetEnumerator() +40
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +315
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   BseWms.WebUI.Controllers.TestController.dateTest() in C:\Users\mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\BseWms\BseWms.WebUI\Controllers\TestController.cs:66
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1.<WrapVoidAction>b__0(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +208
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +263
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +19
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +343
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +116
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
   System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +8970349
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +184
```

and the reportModel class.

```
public class reportModel
{
    public string yourRef {get; set;}
    public string modelNo {get; set;}
    public string mfgNo {get; set;}
    public string serialNo {get; set;}
    public string poNo {get; set;}
    public Nullable<float> lbs { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> width { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> height { get; set; }
    public Nullable<float> depth { get; set; }
    public int qty {get; set;}
    public Nullable<DateTime> dateIn { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> dateOut { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> etaDate { get; set; }
}
```

what's wrong with this code? @.@;

anybody know, please please advice me.

Thanks

[Edit]

@Tyrsius

I tried as your advice, but same error occur.

```
var thedate = new DateTime(2012, 5, 20);
List<reportModel> a = (from q in result
                       where q.etaDate >= thedate
                       select q).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anthing in particular in the InnerException that might give us a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit here

```
List<reportModel> a = (from q in result 
    where q.etaDate >= new DateTime(2012, 5, 20) select q).ToList();
```

Is illegal because EF needs to translate this into SQL, and you can't pass in object constructor like `new Datetime()`. The solution is simple: construct the object before trying to use it in the query

```
var date = new DateTime(2012, 5, 20);
List<reportModel> a = (from q in result 
    where q.etaDate >= date select q).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried as ur advice, but there is still same error. I add the result view into my question, could u review my question again please?

Comment: @Expertwannabe Hmm. The original call to result is being deferred, so it could be tripping on `DefaultIfEmpty` which I believe is not supported by EF. I am guessing you saw someone try to do an outer join with that? If so, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770586/is-an-outer-join-possible-with-linq-to-entity-framework

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that result executes fine you can filter your queries like this:

```
if(filter)
{
    var dateFilter = new DateTime(2012, 5, 20);
    result = result.Where(x => x.etaDate >= dateFilter);
}

return result.ToList(); //or .ToArray()
```

I suggest you put a breakpoint after results executes and see if you have the proper reportModel.
result is alredy casted as an IQueryable, is there a particular reason why you want to cast it to a List?

Hope this helps.